# Counts using a greater than sign

Tags: mysql, count, aggregate-functions

I have a query, that looks like this:

```
SELECT
cat_code, cat_desc,
count(mthtrn > 0),
count(ltmtrn)
from my_temp_table
group by cat_code
order by mthsls desc;
```

How can I get my first `count()` to only get counts with values that are greater than zero, but in the second one get all of them? I can do a greater than with `sum()` but I can't seem to do if for count, even though no error is thrown.

Ideally this would be awesome:

```
SELECT
cat_code, cat_desc,
count(distinct member_id having mthtrn > 0),
count(ltmtrn)
from my_temp_table
group by cat_code
order by mthsls desc;
```

I know it isn't valid, but something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT
cat_code, cat_desc,
count(distinct case when mthtrn > 0 then member_id end),
count(ltmtrn)
from my_temp_table
group by cat_code
order by mthsls desc;
```